Is there any counter example that any infinite triangle construction converge?
Given an Initial Triangle $A_1B_1 C_1$ construct the triangle $A_{n+1}B_{n+1}C_{n+1} $  from $A_n B_n C_n$, where $A_{n+1}$ is the $r_1$-th triangle center of $A_n B_n C_n$,  $B_{n+1}$ is the $r_2$-th triangle center of $A_n B_n C_n$, $C_{n+1}$ is the $r_3$-th triangle center of $A_n B_n C_n$. Where the centers $r_1, r_2 , r_3$ are not collinear.
Like this construction I think this sequence will always converge except for a measure zero set, Proving this would be very difficult if not impossible (since the special case is hard enough) So I want to ask for a counter example, I am not very good at programming so doing a brute force or trial like this is not something I can do (I tried only 3 sets of centers and took me a lot of time)

I think if you start with a very "flat" triangle $ABC$, with $\angle A\approx 180°$ and $AB\ne AC$, and consider incenter, orthocenter and circumcenter, then you'll get a sequence of triangles with increasing flatness whose sides rapidly grow and each rotated by approx. $90°$ with respect to the previous one.

Consideration of generic "$r_1$-th, $r_2$-th, $r_3$-th centers" of a triangle is exceedingly broad. The Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers currently documents over $64000$ centers.

Consider the iteration $$(A,B,C)\to\left(\frac{a^pA+b^pB+c^pC}{a^p+b^p+c^p},\frac{a^qA+b^qB+c^qC}{a^q+b^q+c^q},\frac{a^rA+b^rB+c^rC}{a^r+b^r+c^r}\right)$$ (Eg, $p=0$ gives the centroid; $p=1$, the incenter; $p=2$, the symmedian point; $p=3,4$ give $X(31)$ and $X(32)$; $p=-1,-2$ give $X(75)$ and $X(76)$; etc.) ... Low-Evidence Conjecture: For "many" power triplets $(p,q,r)$, the iteration converges. Maybe. (I tried numerical iterations in Mathematica with a handful of sample triangles and power triples. Apparent convergence seemed to happen within a dozen or so steps.)

@Blue I wonder if this is true more importantly, if it will be useful to prove/disprove it.

@pie: Well, I can guarantee convergence for $p=q=r$. :) ... Beyond that, who knows? I did some symbolic coordinate tinkering with $(p,q,r)=(0,2,-2)$ and $(0,2,4)$ (even powers eliminate square roots in side-length calculations), but things get very messy as soon as the second iteration. Even if my conjecture turns out to be true, I'd be surprised if the limit points have closed-form representations. Analyzing situations like that isn't my forte.

Consider a triangle with two sides of length $a$ and $c$ ($a>c$) and the angle $\beta$ between them near to $\pi$, i.e. its supplementary $t=\pi-\beta$ near to zero.
We can compute the positions of incenter $I$, orthocenter $H$ and circumcenter $O$ of that triangle as a function of $a$, $c$, $t$ and from there compute sides and angles of triangle $IHO$. I won't write down the full expressions, but rather give the asymptotical forms to second order in $t$:
$$
\begin{align}
a'&=IH={a+c\over t}-{a+c\over3}t+O(t^3)\\
c'&=IO={a+c\over 2t}+{a^2+c^2-7ac\over12(a+c)}t+O(t^3)\\
t'&=\pi-\angle HIO={a-c\over a+c}t+O(t^3)
\end{align}
$$
As you can see, the sides $a'$ and $c'$ become larger for $t\ll 1$, always with $a'>c'$ (actually, $a'\approx2c'$), while angle $t$ decreases.
We can then go on computing the next triangle in the sequence and we get the same pattern. Note in particular that $c''\approx{3\over2t}c'$ and $a''\approx 2c''$, while $t''\approx{1\over3}t'$
It is then evident that this sequence of triangles cannot converge, as the lengths of their sides diverge.
